# ActionScript: How to apply different formatting to TextArea content

Tags: actionscript-3, formatting, flex4, textarea

I have a TextArea component called labels that will be populated by Strings in an Array called labelsArray.

Example of labelsArray content:

```
private var labelsArray:Array = new Array( "apple", "*banana", "carrot" );
```

Initially, I populated labels with this statement:

```
labels.text = labelsArray.join( "\n" );
```

If the String is preceded by an asterisk(*) - as is the case with "banana" in the sample content - that String needs to be in a different color AND be surrounded by square brackets []. The asterisk itself is not displayed.

I was not able to find any formatting applied to Strings.

I found out about the TextFormat class to be applied to TextField objects with setTextFormat.

I also found out about the TextLayoutFormat class to be applied to TextArea objects with setFormatOfRange. Unfortunately, I don't under the explanations given for the parameters of setFormatOfRange:

setFormatOfRange( format, anchorPosition, activePosition )
anchorPosition - A character position, relative to the beginning of the text String, specifying the end of the selection that stays fixed when the selection is extended with the arrow keys.
activePosition - A character position, relative to the beginning of the text String, specifying the end of the selection that moves when the selection is extended with the arrow keys.

I don't understand starting from "...specifying the end..." to the end. I don't understand how arrow keys come into play with formatting of text.

Is there something much simpler than this? I'm hoping to loop through labelsArray and apply formatting if needed on each String, and then concatenating/appending it to labels.text.

Thanks for your help!
Bonnie

Comment: Please use Ctrl+K or alternatively select the code and click on the `code` button when posting code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use htmlText property.

```
myTextArea.htmlText = "<font color="red" size="12">String1</font>,
  <font color="green" size="11">String2</font>";
```

Comment: Hi Satish, There seems to be no htmlText attribute for the Spark TextArea component, only for the mx version. Do you know if there's a replacement attribute, or how to simulate htmlText for the Spark version? Thanks, Bonnie

Comment: hmm...look at answers on this post.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326334/display-html-text-in-the-spark-textarea

Comment: Use content property instead of htmlText. Or an another alternate approach: http://polygeek.com/2249_flex_display-html-text-in-the-spark-textarea

Comment: Hi Satish, the polygeek.com link provided the answer. Thanks so much for your help. I'm going to post something else re: applying html tags to data feeding an AdvancedDataGridColumn. Btw, I just tried changing the "0" to something else and it says I need 15 reputations so I'm unable to do it, sorry!